# Java JFrame keeps loading

Tags: java, loading, jframe

Hi this is a stange one for me so I hope you can help :)

I have a method..

```
      public void WMPEGUI(String info)
```

it loads a JFrame...

```
      final JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("JFrame");
```

the method is set up to recieve strings into it to later be wrote out to a text area also created within the method. When I run the program everytime the methods recieves a string it opens a new JFrame I have tried to solve it using...

```
    mainFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    mainFrame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```

But this hasn't solved it, hence asking you kind people. If anyone knows why as I can't find anything on it :/

Many thansk in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your problem is that according to you, your method loads a JFrame. You need to create the JFrame outside that method, somewhere else within the same class, and then refer to it (or to one of it's containers where you will display that string).

Something like this:

> ```
> public class YourClass {
>
> //Class variables
> ...
> JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("JFrame");    
> ...
>
> public void WMPEGUI(String info) {
> ...
> mainFrame.someMethod(...) //or a get for one of its containers
> ...
> }
> ```
>
> }